# Views Send - Send bulk email programatically

Tags: views, 6

This is for Drupal 6.

I've looked around for an answer to this, but I've been unable to find anything. Basically, I'm using hook_cronapi from Ultimate Cron to do a check every 24 hours, and if certain conditions arise, I want to send a bulk email using Views Send.

Super simple example of what I want to accomplish:

```
$view = views_get_view('people_to_email_to');
if (!$view) {
    watchdog('not_real', "Couldn't find view");
    return;
}

$view->set_arguments(array($emailText));
$view->build('email_all');
$view->execute('email_all');

// What do I do from here?
```

As near as I can tell I don't actually send an email on execute, and I can't seem to find documentation which could help. Any ideas?

Comment: You'll have to specify the Drupal version, the D6 and D7 versions of Views Send are very different (one uses VBO, the other doesn't).

Comment: @BojanZivanovic - Good point. I've edited it in and added the 6 tag.